# How can I post on the Facebook user's wall with a metro app (Windows 8)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-8, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm creating a Metro App for Windows 8 with HTML5 and JavaScript, that needs to post a picture on the user's wall.

I'm using Windows Authentication Broker to get the access token, and with that I can get the user data.

The problem is I can't use Facebook SDK for Javascript in a Metro app, that includes the calling to Graph Api to make the post.

So, how can I post something without this? Can I use the way that Windows proposes to sharing data? That is using a DataPackage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465261.aspx )

If it's possible... How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the Facebook Javascript SDK. If you already got the token, you are half way there.

You should send an HTTP POST to "https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos" with the access token (you must have publish_stream permissions). [Facebook API Docs > Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#create)

To send an HTTP post you can use [WinJS.xhr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787) or jQuery.ajax() if you are using jQuery.